# general term for airspeed for objects traveling in a fluid

Tags: single-word-requests

Airspeed is the speed of air relative to an aircraft. Is there a general term for this that applies to any object in any fluid (that is in motion)? For example, if a car were to be driving 10 mph into a 20mph headwind, air would be moving past it at 30mph. Saying that the car has an airspeed of 30mph seems appropriate. But what about a fish swimming in a river?

Comment: For something like a fish, which is moving in the fluid rather than the other way around, I'd tend to use "velocity relative to the fluid" or some such, if simple "speed" seems insufficient.

Comment: Have you checked to see if pilots use the word airspeed in the way you are?

Comment: This is called *relative velocity* in engineering and can be applied to any body moving relative to any fluid whether it's air or water or other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called ***relative velocity*** in engineering and can be applied to any body moving relative to any fluid whether it's air or water or other.

Comment: Relative velocity is a pretty generalized, form what I am reading, it applies to more than just objects in fluids, but any two frames of reference. I suppose I am looking for a term that assumes the object in a fluid, using the object as a fixed frame of reference. I will take it.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to **flow velocity**.

Example: *Thanks to their abrasion resistance, the pipes
remain fully protected even when the flow velocity of water containing solids is very high*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard a specific word, but I have heard modifiers used.
10 knots with the current
10 knots against the current